# Pointers in RubyMotion vs Pointers in MacRuby

Tags: macos, cocoa, keychain, rubymotion, macruby

this works in MacRuby (having required 'Security' framework)

```
error=SecKeychainAddGenericPassword(
                              nil,
                              "someservice".length,
                              "someservice",
                              "someusername".length,
                              "someusername",
                              "somepassword".length,
                              "somepassword".pointer,
                              nil)
```

In RubyMotion, there is no ".pointer" method, so I thought one would have to do :

```
lpointer=Pointer.new(:string)
lpointer.assign("somepassword")
```

But in RubyMotion this does not really store the password on the keychain. The Key is created fine, but there is no password in it.

```
error=SecKeychainAddGenericPassword(
                              nil,
                              "someservice".length,
                              "someservice",
                              "someusername".length,
                              "someusername",
                              "somepassword".length,
                                    lpointer,
                              nil)
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

this is working

```
error=SecKeychainAddGenericPassword(
                              nil,
                              "someservice".length,
                              "someservice",
                              "someusername".length,
                              "someusername",
                              "somepassword".length,
                              "somepassword".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding).bytes
                              nil)
```

.dataUsingEncoding makes an NSData from an NSString, and .bytes makes a Pointer to the data.

Morality : it seems

```
.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding).bytes
```

in RubyMotion is equivalent to

```
.pointer for an NString
```